# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error calling a stored procedure from c# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, data-access

I'm trying to write a web service that calls an oracle stored procedure. The procedure has 2 inputs - a string (company_code) and an int (customer code). It has 2 output parameters; a number (pout_addr_code) and a varchar2 (pout_descr). When I run this procedure from SQL Developer everything works fine and both values are returned as expected. When I call the procedure from my C# web service I get the error "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" on execution, not during the compile.

if I comment out the *cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()* and the *return pout_addr_code.Value...* lines it will run fine and output my test string.

If I remove the varchar2 output from the procedure and comment out the section adding the pout_descr parameter and commenting out the *return "I returned..."* it runs fine, including returning the value from the stored procedure.

So it seems to me the problem is in executing the *NonQuery* when the procedure has the *OracleDbType.Varchar2* line. Is there some other way that this is defined when adding the output parameter in C# using the Oracle.DataAccess reference? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077552/oracle-dataaccess-error-ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-str) asking about a similar error but his solution was to *'specify the max of VARCHAR2 to 32767 in C#'* but I don't see how you do that.

here's my c# code:

```
public string AutoPmtPost(string company_code, int customer_code)
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=MySource; User Id=MyID; Password=MyPassword;";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("USP_JEFF_TEST", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("pin_company_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = company_code;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("pin_customer_code", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = customer_code;

        OracleParameter pout_addr_code = new OracleParameter("pout_addr_code", OracleDbType.Int32);
        pout_addr_code.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pout_addr_code);

        OracleParameter pout_descr = new OracleParameter("pout_descr", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
        pout_descr.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pout_descr);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //return pout_addr_code.Value.ToString();
        return "I returned something";
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
OracleParameter pout_descr = new OracleParameter("pout_descr", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
```

should be

```
OracleParameter pout_descr = new OracleParameter("pout_descr", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000);
```